# Firebase phone authentication no sms for android 12 and below

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

please help me out on this issue. Firebase phone authentication is sending OTP SMS for Android 14 & 13 but not for Android 12 and below.

Is there any configuration that I need to do for Android 12 and below?

Currently I'm following the firebase documentation for phone authentication and I'm using flutter